# Notification on configuration changes in "Profile"

Tags: profile, configuration, notification, user-profile

Can anyone tell me that how to get a notified when any other user make any changes in user profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get notifications for changes to profiles. However, you can view the Setup Audit Trail to view any changes for the past 180 days. This is generally outlined in [Monitor Setup Changes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_monitorsetup.htm).

> Setup Audit Trail tracks the recent setup changes that you and other admins have made to your org. Audit history is especially useful in orgs with multiple admins.
>
> ...
>
> To view the audit history, from Setup, enter View Setup Audit Trail in the Quick Find box, then select View Setup Audit Trail. To download your org’s full setup history for the past 180 days, click Download.